# Unable to resolve superclass of FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I had my environment setup on a previous machine, and I'm on a differnt MacBook. For some strange reason, I keep getting an issue with one of my classes which exend `FragmentActivity`. It keeps saying it can't find the `FragmentActivity` class, although I have the support jar in my class path, as per the image:

[image]

The detailed error message that I'm seeing is here:

```
10-23 23:10:16.300  26062-26062/com.testapp W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/testapp/views/loginregistration/LoginView; (92)
10-23 23:10:16.300  26062-26062/com.testapp W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/testapp/views/loginregistration/LoginView;' failed
10-23 23:10:16.300  26062-26062/com.testapp D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-23 23:10:16.300  26062-26062/com.testapp W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414f8700)
10-23 23:10:16.330  26062-26062/com.testapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.testapp/com.testapp.views.loginregistration.LoginView}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.testapp.views.loginregistration.LoginView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.testapp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.testapp-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.testapp.views.loginregistration.LoginView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.testapp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.testapp-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there someting else i'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your IDE (as shown in your screenshot), check the 'export' box next to the classpath entry that contains the missing class.

I had a similar problem with a class from the Android Support library (Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom ... PagerAdapter). It turned out a library referenced in the .classpath needed to be exported:

From:

```
<classpathentry
```

To:

```
<classpathentry exported="true" ...
```

For Eclipse users, I fixed the problem by exporting Android Private Libraries in the Java Build Path menu.

[image: Checking Android Private Libraries in Eclipse Kepler Java Build Path.]